# Kentico 6.0 Error CS0103

Tags: kentico

I have a Kentico 6 instance. Unfortunately, I imported web part for Kentico 5.5. After recompiling, I get the following error message:

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of
>        a resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>        specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>        Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'CMSCustom' does not exist in
>        the current context
>
> Source Error: Line 31: { Line 32: // Init custom methods Line 33: 
>       CMSCustom.Init(); Line 34: Line 35: // System events Source File: 
>       c:\inetpub\wwwroot\KenticoCMS\App_Code\Global\CMS\Compatibility55.cs
>       Line: 33

How can I make the website operational again?

Answer (score 1):

Kentico 6 added new Macro resolver and event handlers, and Compatibility55.cs file connects the new engine to the old way of customizations. If you don't have any such customizations, you can remove the file Compatibility55.cs, if you have customizations, restore the file CMSCustom.cs that you had before the upgrade.